# href BITMAP from DLL into Webpage

Tags: html, image, dll

I would like to embed 5512.bmp from C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\MSORES.DLL into a HTML document.

I'm expecting to use the res protocol: - however the following doesn't work

`<img src="res://C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\MSORES.DLL/5512.bmp" />`

Note: I have tried replacing all the symbols within the file path to their respective %## codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that; the `res://` URL scheme, like the `file://` URL scheme and various other "unsafe" schemes, [cannot be referenced from the Internet zone in MSIE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767740(v=vs.85).aspx).

Upload the image to your web site and link to it normally.

Comment: The link will be hosted from an intranet page, and testing is being done from N:\test.html, which is within the local intranet zone.